# PHP What does function statement., variable not persistent

Tags: php, variables, scope, goutte

I am trying to use some Goutte code :

```
$oldtext='';
// Get the latest post in this category and display the titles
$crawler->filter('h2 > a')->each(function ($node) {
    print $node->text()."\n";
    $oldtext=$node->text();
    print $oldtext."\n";
});
```

I have 2 questions :

1. what does statement "function ($node)" it's kind of inline function definition
2. why $oldtext variable it's not presistent ? it's like inside of "function ($node)" all variables are reinitiated

Comment: It is a [closure function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Change `function ($node) {` to `function ($node) use (&$oldtext){` to make it persistent across calls.